# Showing in general way that three square pyramids can combine to form a cuboid having same dimensions as square pyramid Visually

Tags: geometry, volume, proof-without-words

I know that volume of a square base pyramid of bottom square area $S$ and height $H$ is given by $\frac{1}{3}SH $ , and volume of a square base cuboid outside having dimensions exactly that to be $SH$ .

- My question is how can we visually show that we can keep three of those pyramids inside it ?

> Note:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590144/922054  in this post they showed visually that **for a cube** it can be divided into three same pyramids, but what i am asking is in general (that is cuboid shape) not cube only.

- They showed for a unique relation between height of the pyramid and square base side
  the relation being √S = H ,since then only that cube is possible to be made.